# I cannot load the node information on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

When I ran the command below, I got the below messages

```
bistel@BISTelResearchDev-DN03:~$ kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

While in the master node, I get the information as below:

```
bistel@BISTelResearchDev-NN:/etc/kubernetes$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                     STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
bistelresearchdev-dn03   NotReady   <none>   62s   v1.19.3
bistelresearchdev-nn     Ready      master   57m   v1.19.3
bistel@BISTelResearchDev-NN:/etc/kubernetes$
```

The `bistelresearchdev-dn03` is the worker node and the message appears when I ran any command using `kubectl` as follows `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`.

I googled it a lot but any trials didn't work for me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kubectl` works only on master node in cluster. If you are getting this error then there is no issue.
I can see the issue here is node is `NotReady` status for that you can check below things.

1. Check kubelet is running on node `bistelresearchdev-dn03` with `systemctl status kubelet`
2. Check network plugin is installed on your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The first computer you ran on is missing the kube config file.

Normally kubectl expects to find it at
~/.kube/config

If you get the one off the master node and copy it onto your machine your kubectl will see it and be able to use it.